# CSS stylesheet applied inside and outside of iframe

Tags: html, css, iframe

I am working on a kind of funky 3rd party website where I have access to the CSS files but cannot modify the actual html or JavaScript files. I changed the background on the site but I found later the css also applied to web parts inside of iframes. The same css file is linked inside of these iframes so the background tags I am applying to the outer html body {} are also applied to the inner set.

Is there any way to add another selector that only applies if it is inside of an iframe or is there no way for it to figure that out? I have tried iframe html body {} and #name-of-iframe body {} but these don't even show as being associated with the inner body in the browser. 
Is this something that can be done? Any insight is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately you would need to run Javascript to determine if you're running inside an iframe or not. CSS by itself is not sufficient.

You might look for differences in the markup between the two pages-- for example, maybe the `<body>` element has a different ID or class on pages inside the iframe.

Comment: Thank you, I was not able to find any differences in html or body I could use but there was a unique div right below it that I was able to cover up the original background with. It is not ideal but only a few people need to access those iframes and they only need to be readable. Thanks again